# Weird notation for logarithm (from a 1887 trigonometry book)

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, logarithms

I am struggling with this 1887 trigonometry book's page in which the author's is teaching how to compute the size of an arc associated with an angle x.

Everything is preety easy until he talks about the need of logarithms to do that and I don't even know what that bracket notation means, does that mean the log of the quantity inside the bracket? if so what is the base for that?

Please, help me to understand the notation and, if possible, what is he doing when he calculates that example. Thank You all.

Update: Guys, thank you , I got it all and I was able to reproduce the calculations, there is one remaining doubt, how did they do 10^x with these numbers in the end, did they use some sort of polynomial aproximation such as taylor? Thank you again.

[image: Page I am fighting with]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\log_{10}(0.017453293) + 10 &= 8.24187738 \\
\log_{10}(0.000290882) + 10 &= 6.46371685
\end{align}

I am not sure why the values are shifted by a factor of $10^{10}$; it may have to do with the fact that the author chose to normalize everything to 9 digits past the decimal point and the particular presentation of the log table he has on hand. 
This is presumably explained in the footnote or endnote attached to the asterisk symbol that you managed to omit from the picture your question.

---

In terms of what the author is doing with the examples: in modern language, the quantity the author denotes by $x$ (the arc length), is simply the angle measured in *radians* when the circle has radius 1. (Other wise you have to multiply by the radius.) The page you included in your question shows how to convert from *degrees* into *radians*. In modern trigonometry classes, you would've been taught that the formula is

$$ \text{radians} = \frac{2\pi}{360} \times \text{degrees} $$

130 years ago they don't have calculators, and the fastest way to multiply numbers with many digits is using a log table. So you have that

$$ \log (\text{radians}) = \log (\frac{2\pi}{360}) + \log (\text{degrees}) $$

and addition is considerably easier than multiplication.

The final step then is to know what to add: so the author gives you the value of $\log(2\pi / 360)$ (offset by 10) for converting from degrees to radians, and also the value of $\log(2\pi/21600)$ for converting from minutes to radians, and also the value of $\log(2\pi /1296000)$ for converting from seconds to radians.

Comment: Thank you very much, Now I understand everything. 

The asterisk symbol just mention the table ( Stanley's table ) haha, Something famous back then I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well before calculators, the way to express a base 10 logarithm $0<x<1$ was to write $-10$ after the number.

In the examples above, $[8.2418774]° = 8.2418774-10$.

As Willie Wong explained above, addition of logarithms was much easier than carrying out multiplication.